# Without using Heegner-Stark-Baker, $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-11})$ has class number $1$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, geometry, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

> Prove that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-11})$ is of class number $1$.

I have found that the ideal $(2)$ of the integer ring $\mathbb{Z}[(1 + \sqrt{-11})/2]$ of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-11})$ is a prime ideal. But I am not sure where to go from there. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: http://math.blogoverflow.com/2014/08/23/binary-quadratic-forms-over-the-rational-integers-and-class-numbers-of-quadratic-%EF%AC%81elds/

Comment: I think with a smidgen of cleverness one can show that this ring of integers is (norm-) Euclidean, for example.

Comment: Have you heard of the Minkowski Bound?

Comment: How about Bachman Turner Overdrive?

Comment: Minkowski bound is $2\sqrt{11}/\pi\approx 2.11143$, and you have checked ideals of norm two, so looks like you're done? Read [this set of examples from Planetmath](http://planetmath.org/usingminkowskisconstanttofindaclassnumber).

Answer (score 10):

Prove that $\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1 + \sqrt{-11}}2]$ is an ED, which is just alike the case of $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-1}]$. The core is that for any $a+b\sqrt{-11}\in\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-11})$, there exists an element $z\in\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1 + \sqrt{-11}}2]$ such that, if we write $a+b\sqrt{-11}=z+r+t\sqrt{-11}$, then $\vert r\vert\leqslant\frac12,\ \vert t\vert\leqslant\frac14$, and consequently, $N(r+t\sqrt{-11})<1$.

With the help of this lemma, for any two elemnts $x,y\in\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1 + \sqrt{-11}}2]$ with $y\neq0$, we can find an $z\in\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1 + \sqrt{-11}}2]$ such that $\frac xy=z+r+t\sqrt{-11}$ and $N(r+t\sqrt{-11})<1$, or equivalently, $ x=yz+y(r+t\sqrt{-11})$ and $N(y(r+t\sqrt{-11}))<N(y)$ (note also that $y(r+t\sqrt{-11})=x-yz\in\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1 + \sqrt{-11}}2]$). So Euclidean algorithm is applicable.

[image]

The figure has some elements of $\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1 + \sqrt{-11}}2]$ (dots) and the above regions (grey rectangles) centered around some points $z\in \mathbb{Z}[\frac{1 + \sqrt{-11}}2]$.

Comment: +1 I wanted to see what the picture looks like. I took the liberty of adding an image to your answer. Feel free to remove it, if you think it makes it too easy it follow up on your hint.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen A nice picture. Thanks a lot for helping me with improving my answer!

Comment: Why downvote? Any error?

Answer (score 6):

The Euclidean algorithm says for any $a,b \in \mathcal{O}_K$ there is a quotient and remainder $q,r \in \mathcal{O}_K$ with $N(r)<N(q)$ such that $a=bq+r$.

Another way of thinking about it is to divide both side by $b$ and say

$$ \frac{a}{b}=q+   \frac{r}{b}$$

So that every rational number can be represented as the sum of a lattice point $q \in \mathcal{O}_K$ and element of unit disk $N( \frac{r}{b})<1$.

Once we **prove** the existence of the Euclidean algorithm for $K=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-11})$  then unique factorization into primes follows.  Every Euclidean domain is a principal ideal domain.

---

The norm for the ring of integers  $\mathbb{Z}\left[\frac{1 + \sqrt{-11}}{2}\right]$ is a binary quadratic form over $\mathbb{Z}$.

$$\big|\big|x + \tfrac{1 + \sqrt{-11}}{2}y \big|\big|^2 = x^2 + xy + 3y^2 \hspace{0.25in}\text{and}\hspace{0.25in}
\big|\big| \tfrac{m + n\sqrt{-11}}{2} \big|\big|^2 = \frac{1}{4}(m^2 + 11n^2 )
$$

The "unit circle" for this norm is actually an ellipse
with $ Area(\bigcirc)= \frac{4\pi}{11} >1 = Area(\square) $

The oval area is just slightly bigger than the fundamental area of the lattice, so you are fine by [Minkowski](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/541665/fermats-2-square-like-results-from-minkowski-lattice-proofs).

---

Check it out! The Minkowski sum of the integer lattice $\mathbb{Z}\left[\tfrac{1 + \sqrt{-11}}{2}\right]$  and the unit circle $||z|| < 1$ covers the entire plane:

[image]
[image]

This is no longer true for $\mathbb{Z}\left[\tfrac{1 + \sqrt{-19}}{2}\right]$.

Comment: See Master's Thesis of Abebe Simachew (Ethiopia / Boreaux) [**A Survey of Euclidean Number Fields**](http://algant.eu/documents/theses/simachew.pdf)

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/957224/showing-mathbbz-mathbbz-frac1-sqrt-m2-is-a-euclidean-domain?rq=1

Comment: Possibly related [Dense Packings from Algebraic Number Fields and Codes](http://front.math.ucdavis.edu/1506.00419) Shantian Cheng